# Java char literal to C# char literal

Tags: c#, java, character

I am maintaining some Java code that I am currently converting to C#.

The Java code is doing this:

`sendString(somedata + '\000');`

And in C# I am trying to do the same:

`sendString(somedata + '\000');`

But on the '\000' VS2010 tells me that "Too many characters in character literal". How can I use '\000' in C#? I have tried to find out what the character is, but it seems to be " " or some kind of newline-character.

Do you know anything about the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'\0'` will be just fine in C#.

What's happening is that C# sees `\0` and converts that to a nul-character with an ASCII value of 0; then it sees two more `0`s, which is illegal inside a *character* (since you used single quotes, not double quotes).  The nul-character is typically not printable, which is why it looked like an empty string when you tried to print it.

What you've typed in Java is a character literal supporting an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number.  C# does not support octal literals in characters *or* numbers, in an effort to reduce programming mistakes.<sup>*</sup>

[C# *does* supports Unicode literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28VS.71%29.aspx) of the form `'\u0000'` where `0000` is a 1-4 digit hexadecimal number.

<sup>*</sup>  In PHP, for example, if you type in a number with a leading zero that is a valid octal number, it gets translated.  If it's not a legal octal number, it doesn't get translated correctly.  `<? echo 017; echo ", "; echo 018; ?>` outputs `15, 1` on my machine.

Comment: Heh... we wrote practically the same. +1

Answer (score 4):

That's a [null character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm), also known as NUL. You can write it as '\0' in C#.

In C# the string "\000" represents three characters: the null character, followed by two zero digits. Since a character literal can only contain one character, this is why you get the error "Too many characters in character literal".

Comment: And we're both named Mark... so +1 to you too.